# Grails: Understanding error from method added from Plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-3.0

I am trying to port the jGit plugin to Grails 3.

This plugin adds a method 'withJGit' to some classes (default 'Controller','Service' and 'Domain', but configurable from Config.groovy in Grails 2.x).

I have made all the changes I thought necessary for Grails 3, but when our application tries to call 'withJGit' the following error occurs:

```
No signature of method: app.GitService.withJGit() is applicable
for argument types: (app.GitService$_updateData_closure1) 
values: [app.GitService$_updateData_closure1@2e4d8f4a] 
Possible solutions: withJGit(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

The definition of 'withJGit' in the plugin is:

```java
private void addDynamicMethods(klass, jgit) {
    klass.metaClass.withJGit = withJGit.curry(jgit)
}

private withJGit = { jgit, Closure closure ->
    if (!closure) return

    closure.delegate = jgit
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    closure(jgit.rootFolder)
}
```

Why does this give the 'No signature' error?
What is wrong with this dynamic method definition?

The 'jgit' in the above code is a springbean implementing the interface to the underlying jgit library

I thought I had a pretty good understanding of Groovy, but this baffles me

The work-in-progress code can be found here: https://github.com/anwbhv/grails-jgit/tree/grails3